# Is O((n-1)(n-3)(n-5)...(n-n+1)) considered O(n!) running time?

Tags: time-complexity

I found the worst-case running time of my algorithm to be O((n-1)(n-3)(n-5)...(n-n+1)). Is this considered O(n!) or does it simplify to a lower running time?

Comment: Use the definition. Divide by n! and take the limit as n goes to infinity. Note that both statements can be true: it can be both O(n!) *and* something lower.

Comment: (n-1)(n-3)(n-5)...(n-n+1) is (n-1)!! where the double !! stands for "double factorial". For an even non negative integer n = 2k, the double factorial may be expressed as n!! = 2^k k!. This being said, I think that it's still O(n!)

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps we can use to come up with the answer for `n!!` in terms of `n!` and `n`.
Firstly, in `n!!`, we have half as many terms as we would in `n!`. So we can imagine taking `n!` and 'dividing out' `(n/2)!`. So this is
`1*2*3*4...n / (1*2*3*4...n/2)` in the first step.

However, this isn't quite right, since we want to remove all the even numbers, not all the numbers less than n/2! What's nice, however, is that now we can take every term in the denominator, individually, and multiply it by 2 to get `2*4*6*8...(n-2)*n`. If we then 'factor out' all the *2s that we just used, we'd have exactly (n/2) of them (since there were n/2 elements in this sequence, and we doubled all of them). Thus, `n!! = n! / ((n/2)! * 2^(n/2))`. So, `O(1*3*5*7...*(n-2)*n)` = `O(n!/((n/2)!2^(n/2))` which is better than `n!` (since we're at least dividing an exponential and a smaller factorial!). Hope this makes sense

Answer (score -1):

Firsty, when you talk about running time you should use T(n) = (n - 1)(n - 3)..(n - n + 1). Secondly, it is not considered O(n!), you can provide better evalution for worst-case time complexity:

- 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * n = n!
- 2 * 4 * 8 * ... * n = 2^(n/2) * (n/2)!

divide equations

1 * 3 * 5 * ... * n = n! / (2^(n/2) * (n/2)!)

So, your final worst-case complexity is O(n! / (2^(n/2) * (n/2)!)) and it's pretty obvious why this evaluations is different from O(n!).